# gdal: create a tile index or VRT from a folder of downloaded map tiles

Tags: gdal, wms, wmts, gdalbuildvrt, gdaltindex

I need to use GDAL tools to either create a tile index or create a VRT from a folder full of map tiles. The folder is in the format:

```
<zoom_level>
     |
     |-- <row_number>
     |       |
     |       |-- <column_number>.png
     |       |-- <column_number>.png
     |-- <row_number>
     |       |
     .       |-- <column_number>.png
     .       |-- <column_number>.png
```

They're standard slippy-grid / MTS / WMS tiles, all png files.

I can't seem to figure out the right command to do this... does anyone know what I should do here?

Comment: Those tools can't be used that way because the image files themselves are not georeferenced.

Comment: What tools would I need to use, in that case? I could pretty trivially, say, spit out a JSON or XML file containing the corner coordinates for each tile... is there a format in which I could do that, and then be able to pull the files in as a VRT?

Comment: @user30184 https://www.gdal.org/frmt_wms.html This seems to imply that you can use WMS tiles as a data source, and it looks like the `<cache>` element would allow me to read in local files... that said, there's a lot in here that's a bit over my head.

Comment: By enabling <cache> gdal creates its cache on disk. I do not know if GDAL is using exactly similar directory structure than you have. If it  does it should indeed be possible to point GDAL to use your ready made cache. Another option could be to use the TMS minidriver that is documented on the same page but by default it wants to reach the tiles through http, not directly from disk.